# XSD Files with Disabled Fields

Tags: c#, vb.net, xsd, xsd-validation

Say I have a XML Schema (XSD) and there are record fields that have Enabled=True and some record fields that have Enabled=false. Is there a way, when reading a XML file to store in to a List object to validate against the XSD and only read the record fields that have Enabled=True?

Comment: Why don't you want to validate the entire xml file? Then read only elements that have enabled= true.

Comment: I am not sure how to read only ones with enabled. Say the record in the XML files has 10 fields. The XSD has 8 fields enabled and 2 fields disabled. When I read the XML, My object should only contain 8 fields not 10 because of the disabled fields in the XSD.

Comment: I usually use XML Linq (XELEMENT). Need to see sample to help.

Comment: Problem is I do not have the XSD with the disabled fields. I have the XML file that contains each records and the fields in each record. If I knew how to generate the XSD with disabled fields I could probably solve it

Comment: You set the enable in the XML, not the XSD.

Comment: @jdweng How do I do that, can you give me an example please

Comment: @jdweng I am being told this as the requirement. The dataset file you will be testing has 10 records and 10 fields per record. The dataset schema has 8 enabled fields and 2 disabled ones.

Comment: I need sample.  without seeing format it really not possible to give an answer.